# Using json data on a server in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following data on http://www.abcd.com/friends.json (this is not a real link but I am using one that is real on my project and I can connect to the server):

```
{John, Kyle, Abby, Greer, Rob, Cathy}
```

and I have the following script to autocomplete a text field:

```
$(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: $.getJSON("http://www.abcd.com/friends.json")
});
  });
```

or

```
$(function() {
  var friendList = null;
  $.getJSON("http://www.abcd.com/friends.json", function(data){
     friendList = data;
     $("#friend" ).autocomplete({
    source: friendList
    });
  });
});
```

what am I doing wrong? both codes work if the json object is not called from a remote server
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid. Probably you want to have something like this:

```
[ 'John', 'Kyle', 'Abby', 'Greer','Rob', 'Cathy' ]
```

Another possible error (as mentioned by JiDai in the comments) could be that you're getting the JSON from another server than your page is served. In that case either move your JSON to the same server or implement some [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) schema.

Comment: Thanks Sirko, Correction made no changes in result.

Comment: I have the server address correctly. There is only one server and not sure how the JSON can come from another server.

Comment: @Aamare is your code returning any errors or is there simply no autocomplete appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please replace "source" with "serviceUrl"

```
$(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: "http://www.abcd.com/friends.json"
    });
});
```